# how to extract .dll class library in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#

I upgraded Visual Studio into 2012, can't find the button to extract .dll into Desktop, they seem to have changed the buttons.

I have a class library in c# solution. I want to create .dll file to use it in different solutions.

Comment: "extract .dll to desktop"? Why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: What does "extract .dll to desktop" even mean?

Comment: Which DLL are you trying to extract? From your project?

Comment: **can't find the button to extract .dll into Desktop**...what does that mean????

Comment: I have a class library in c# solution. I want to create .dll file to use it in different solutions.

Comment: @HasanYılmaz, that is made for you when build the project. It's in your bin directory by default. Are you trying to move it to a different location or use it in another project in your solution?

Comment: Gustavo solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are trying to get a DLL from your project, you need to **build** the project and look for it inside the `bin` folder of your project. So you may reference it in another projects.

Comment: solved my question.... thanks !